# Grammatical Erratum?

Tags: grammar

So I'm writing an essay , and have inserted the following phrase in it :-
" .... to correct any spelling mistakes or grammatical erratum".
Is it alright to use the word 'erratum' in this context? If not , any other suggestions if it isn't?

Comment: Since you're using the plural "mistakes", you should also use the plural "errata" (which is the more-commonly-seen form of the word anyway).  I don't have a problem with "errata" but it is certainly a 'high-register' word; you might be better off with something like '... any mistakes in spelling or grammar.'

Comment: @Hellion , Thanks for the reply , ill do the same. So I'm assuming the sentence is correctly worded , then?

Comment: Conversely, you could singularize the whole thing: ". . . any spelling mistake or grammatical erratum."

Comment: Keeping the register level avoids distraction. As does not using foreign words from a language one doesn't understand.

Comment: @Hellion, but since *erratum* does not mean "mistake", then the plural is only grammatically better, in that it now means "correct grammatical corrections" rather than "correct grammatical correction". It's grammatical, but still wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

One could argue for *errata*, as the plural of *erratum*, but that would still not be quite correct.

While the Latin *erratum*  refers to mistakes, it is a verb rather than a noun and so not reasonable to directly borrow from Latin in that sense.

The Latin *errata corrige* ("mistaken, and then corrected") has given English both *erratum* (plural *errata*) and *corrigendum* (plural *corrigenda*) as synonyms, meaning a note stating a correction, often listed in a sheet or appendix titled "Errata" (or "Corrigenda"), since even if there was only a single erratum one might reasonably expect further errata to come.

For the mistakes themselves, the normal word would be *errors*, from the same Latin root.:

> …to correct any spelling mistakes or grammatical errors.

Is perfectly good English, with the meaning you intend, suitable for formal and reasonably formal registers.

Comment: +1 But *... mistakes or ... errors* strikes me as elegant variation.

Comment: @StoneyB as elegant (in which case why the "but"?) or as inelegant?

Comment: ["Elegant variation"](http://www.bartleby.com/116/302.html) is the scornful name the Fowlers gave the Victorian practice of employing synonyms for the sake of variety.

Comment: @StoneyB and of course it is, I should have remembered that.
I find this one elegant enough in the straight sense, because the repetition of [modifier][noun] appeals. Whether I'd think so in the context of a full real paragraph is another matter.

Comment: @JonHanna, checking 3 online dictionaries (wiktionary, m-w, and freedictionary) shows a definition for *erratum* (plural *errata*) of "an error in printing or writing", with the optional specific sense of a sheet denoting such errors and their corrections.  And isn't arguing that the original Latin word was a verb an example of the etymological fallacy?  We clearly have been using it as a noun for a very long time.

Comment: @Hellion not an etymological fallacy (as then I would argue it couldn't be used at all) as not knowing of it used that way, I was considering the possibility of a novel borrowing. I note M-W does say ("especially corrigendum"), as does freedictionary, while wiktionary gives that use first for the plural *errata*. As such I don't think I was awry in thinking of that as how the word is actually used.